# How to do an if-else condition for Image Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I do an if-else condition for Image Control in ASP.NET if it is empty? If it is not empty, btnSave (Button) is enabled.

```
if (imageControl.Image != NULL)
{
btnSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: have you tried something like: `imageControl.Image != null`

Comment: Hi @JensKloster, I have tried it before. The button was not enabled after the if-else condition.

Answer (score 2):

asp.net imageControl has ImageUrl property where the path of the image file is located. you can check this property weather it is blank or empty as shown below:

```
if(imageControl.ImageUrl!=""){
    btnSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "empty" you mean ImageUrl is not set then

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageControl.ImageUrl))
{
    btnSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

If by "empty" you mean ImageUrl indeed contains some meaningfull image, you have to tackle the resulting

```
<img />
```

tag on client side.

Comment: Hi, thank you. However, the button was not enabled. After the imageControl contains an image, the button will then be enabled.

Comment: Sorry - I missed the negation (!)

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate more - show your .aspx/.ascx with the parts of imageControl and btnSave involved. Also where are you calling this code in code behind ?

Comment: @LiuJiaHui: by showing the code it helps us to resolve the issue.

Comment: This code is calling from a drop down list. When I choose a value let say 'A'. The 'A' will be draw onto a default image using DrawString. Then it will appear in imgImage(Image Control). Then the btnSave is enabled.